# Utilizando ConnectionString, aparece el error Palabra clave no admitida: 'version'

Tags: c#, sqlite

Estoy haciendo un sistema con C# y esta vez estoy usando SQLite para la Base de Datos. En el App.config puse:

```
<add name="cadena" connectionString="Data Source=.\db.db; Version=3;" />
```

luego en una clase puse la variable como pública así:

```
public static string stringConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadena"].ConnectionString;
```

en una clase que es como mi controlador mando a llamar para hacer una consulta así:

```
string cs = Globales.stringConnection;
string query= "SELECT....";
using(SQLConnection conn = new SQLConnection(cs)){conn.Open}
```

ya cuando está haciendo el proceso de leer el controlador me manda el mensaje de:

> Palabra clave no admitida: 'version'.

¿Alguien me puede decir dónde está el error o qué es lo que pasa?

Comment: me falto poner que cs es: string cs = Globales.stringConnection;

Comment: El problema es simple: estás intentando conectar a SQLite como si fuera SQL Server, revisa este ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1253002/3613462 Saludos.